# Giving plotted lines from a graph in excel a value to read new value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

Given the graph attached in this post:

```
Dark blue plotted line -> r=0
orange plotted line -> r=1
gray plotted line -> r=2
yellow plotted line -> r=3
light blue plotted line -> r=4
```

I need some help by getting my 'r' value by a calculated X and Y value. For example (as seen in the picture): If X is calculated at 0,15 and Y is calculated at 0.83, r should be ~1,5 (in the mid of the orange (r=1) and gray (r=2) lines.

Is there any way to do this in Excel?

Thanks
[image: Attached picture]

Comment: Probably, but since we don't know what the relationship between those values are, there's not much we can suggest. In any case, this would not be done from the chart, but from the data used to generate it, which we also don't have

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks. Any suggestions on how to do so? The lines are plotted by known values (dots are shown in graph))